# ExcelからTwitter（selenium）で特定の条件がある場合、繰り返し処理を行う方法について

Tags: python, python3, twitter, selenium

#### 前提・実現したいこと

python:seleniumを使って
Excelから繰り返しデータを読み、[Twitter](https://twitter.com/search-advanced?lang=en)で複数のデータを検索したいです。
B列に同じ国が2つ以上ある場合、[Twitter](https://twitter.com/search-advanced?lang=en)で下記のように検索したいです。

#### Excel データ

```
1   アメリカ カリフォルニア 
1   アメリカ　フロリダ
2   フランス  パリ
3   日本   　東京
```

#### 検索したい順番

```
アメリカ "カリフォルニア" (フロリダ) →１回目のループで検索したい内容
フランス "パリ" →2回目のループで検索したい内容
日本 "東京" →3回目のループで検索したい内容
```

下記のコードだと試してみましたが、
検索したい順番で上手くループされず、
B列に同じ国が2つ以上ある場合、ループはどのように指定すればよろしいでしょうか。

Forについてあまり詳しくないですが、Forをこちらの部分に追加すればよろしいでしょうか。

```
 #都市が2つ以上がある場合
    c2 = v_ws['c2'].value   
    print(c2)

    #都市2つ以上がある場合、c列を入力(現在固定)⇒データが不定期の場合、ループさせたい部分
    city2 = driver.find_element_by_name("anyOfTheseWords")
    city2.send_keys(c2)
```

**現在の検索の結果**

```
アメリカ "カリフォルニア" (フロリダ) →１回目のループで検索
アメリカ "カリフォルニア" (フロリダ)→2回目のループで検索
フランス "パリ" (フロリダ)→3回目のループで検索
日本 "東京" (フロリダ)→4回目のループで検索
```

**Code**

```
# Excel用ライブラリ読込
import openpyxl
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select  
from selenium import webdriver
import pyautogui

# Excelファイルを開く
v_wb=openpyxl.load_workbook("test.xlsx")

# アクティブなシートを変数へ
v_ws = v_wb.active
# シートのロード
ws = v_wb.worksheets[0]

#1行目からループを行う
for i in range(1,v_ws.max_row+1):

    #国b列
    b = v_ws['b'+str(i)].value

    #都市c列
    c = v_ws['c'+str(i)].value
    print(c)

    #都市が2つ以上がある場合
    c2 = v_ws['c2'].value   
    print(c2)

    URL= "https://twitter.com/search-advanced?lang=en"

    # ブラウザを開く。 #options=option background 
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Program Files\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe")

    # Googleの検索TOP画面を開く。
    driver.get(URL)

    # 2秒待機
    time.sleep(2)

    #country
    country = driver.find_element_by_name("allOfTheseWords")
    country.send_keys(b)
    
    # 2秒待機
    time.sleep(2)

    #都市のc列を入力
    city = driver.find_element_by_name("thisExactPhrase")
    city.send_keys(c)

    #都市2つ以上がある場合、c列を入力(現在固定)⇒データが不定期の場合、ループさせたい部分
    city2 = driver.find_element_by_name("anyOfTheseWords")
    city2.send_keys(c2)

    #検索
    time.sleep(2)
    pyautogui.press(['enter'])

#ここまでを繰り返し --------------------------------------------------------------------
```

#### 補足情報（Python/ツールのバージョンなど）

Python3/Windows10を利用しています。

もしわかる方いれば、教えていただけるとありがたいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

以下では前回の回答と同様に Excel のシートを Pandas のデータフレームに変換しています。
生成される検索ワードの組み合わせは以下の様になります。

```
[['アメリカ', 'カリフォルニア', 'フロリダ'], ['フランス', 'パリ'], ['日本', '東京']]
```

都市名が2個ある場合には要素数が3個になるので、その場合は `anyOfTheseWords` 欄に2個目の都市名を入力する様にしています。

なお、デバッグ目的で Google Chrome を detach しているのと、検索する度に新規にタブを開いています。適宜変更してください。

```py
# Excel用ライブラリ読込
import openpyxl
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select  
from selenium import webdriver
import pyautogui
import pandas as pd

# Excelファイルを開く
v_wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("test.xlsx")

# アクティブなシートを変数へ
v_ws = v_wb.active
# シートのロード
ws = v_wb.worksheets[0]

# convert to pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(ws.values)

# generate search words
lst = (
  df.groupby(1, as_index=False)[2]
    .agg(lambda x: x.tolist())
    .apply(lambda x: [x[1]] + x[2], axis=1)
    .tolist()
)
print(lst)

URL = "https://twitter.com/search-advanced?lang=en"

# ブラウザを開く。 #options=option background 
options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option('detach', True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Program Files\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe", options=options)

for i, query in enumerate(lst):
    # Googleの検索TOP画面を開く。
    if i > 0:
      driver.execute_script('window.open()')
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[i])
    driver.get(URL)

    # 2秒待機
    time.sleep(2)

    # country
    country = driver.find_element_by_name("allOfTheseWords")
    country.send_keys(query[0])

    # 2秒待機
    time.sleep(2)

    # 都市のc列を入力
    city = driver.find_element_by_name("thisExactPhrase")
    city.send_keys(query[1])

    # 都市2つ以上がある場合、c列を入力(現在固定)⇒データが不定期の場合、ループさせたい部分
    if len(query) > 2:
      city2 = driver.find_element_by_name("anyOfTheseWords")
      city2.send_keys(query[2])

    # 検索
    time.sleep(2)
    pyautogui.press(['enter'])
```

Comment: @metropoloisさん
早速、丁寧な回答ありがとうございます。
上記の方法で試してみましたが`AttributeError:'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'tolist'`のエラーが表示されます。DataFrameオブジェクトにはtolistは利用出来ないでしょうか。ご確認をお願い致します。

Comment: Numpyをインポートして上記のエラーを解消できるか。試してみます。

Comment: こちらの Pandas のバージョンは `1.3.1` ですが、そちらでお使いの Pandas のバージョンはどうなっていますでしょうか。

Comment: 返事ありがとうございます。`1.2.4`になります。

Comment: `$ pip install -U <pandas>`で`1.3.1 `へUpdateしましたら問題なく出来ました。ありがとうございます。