# seleniumを使ってTwitterのキーワードを複数検索したい

Tags: python3, selenium, selenium-webdriver

**前提・実現したいこと**
python:seleniumを使って
Excelから繰り返しデータを読み、[Twitter](https://twitter.com/search-advanced?lang=jp)で複数のデータを検索したいです。
C列に都市2つ以上ある場合、Twitterで下記のように検索したいです。

#### Excel データ

| No | 国 | 都市 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | アメリカ | ロスアンゼルス、ニューヨーク、カリフォルニア |
| 2 | 日本 | 東京、京都 |
| 3 | オーストラリア | シドニー |

#### 検索したい順番

```
アメリカ ロスアンゼルス、ニューヨーク、カリフォルニア →１回目のループで検索したい内容
日本 東京、京都 →2回目のループで検索したい内容
オーストラリア シドニー →3回目のループで検索したい内容
```

都市2つ以上がある場合、カンマで区切って、下記のように検索したいです。

```
　　　　　　　　#国b列の次のキーワードを全て含むへ入力
    #例アメリカ入力
    country = driver.find_element_by_name("allOfTheseWords")
    country.send_keys(b)
    
    # 2秒待機
    time.sleep(2)

    #都市c列を次のキーワード全体を含むへ入力
    #例ロスアンゼルス入力
    city = driver.find_element_by_name("thisExactPhrase")
    city.send_keys(c)

    #都市c列２つ以上がある場合
    #都市c列を次のキーワードのいずれかを含むへ入力
    #ニューヨーク入力
    if list>list[1]:
     city = driver.find_element_by_name("anyOfTheseWords")
     city.send_keys(list[1])

    #都市c列3つ以上がある場合
    #都市c列を次のキーワードを含まないへ入力
    #カリフォルニア入力
    if list>list[2]:
     city = driver.find_element_by_name("noneOfTheseWords")
     city.send_keys(list[2])
```

現在、Twitterで下記のように検索しています。
③でTypeErrorエラーされます。また②には**ロスアンゼルス、ニューヨーク、カリフォルニア**全ての都市が入力されます。
カンマで区切ってロスアンゼルスのみ入力したいです。

```
①次のキーワードを全て含むへ入力
アメリカ入力

②次のキーワード全体を含むへ入力
ロスアンゼルス、ニューヨーク、カリフォルニア　

③次のキーワードのいずれかを含むへ入力
エラー
if list>list[1]:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'str
```

全体コード

```
# Excel用ライブラリ読込
import openpyxl
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select  
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# Excelファイルを開く
v_wb=openpyxl.load_workbook("twitter.xlsx")

# アクティブなシートを変数へ
v_ws = v_wb.active
# シートのロード
ws = v_wb.worksheets[0]

# ブラウザを開く。 #options=option background 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())

#TWITTER URL
URL= "https://twitter.com/search-advanced?lang=jp"

# Googleの検索TOP画面を開く。
driver.get(URL)


#2行目からループを行う
for i in range(2,v_ws.max_row+1):

    #国b列を読み込む
    b = v_ws['b'+str(i)].value

    #都市c列を読み込む
    c = v_ws['c'+str(i)].value
    print(b)

    #都市をカンマ区切りの文字リスト化
    list = c.split('、')
    print(list)

    # 2秒待機
    time.sleep(2)

    #国b列の次のキーワードを全て含むへ入力
    #例アメリカ入力
    country = driver.find_element_by_name("allOfTheseWords")
    country.send_keys(b)
    
    # 2秒待機
    time.sleep(2)

    #都市c列を次のキーワード全体を含むへ入力
    #例ロスアンゼルス入力
    city = driver.find_element_by_name("thisExactPhrase")
    city.send_keys(c)

    #都市c列２つ以上がある場合
    #都市c列を次のキーワードのいずれかを含むへ入力
    #ニューヨーク入力
    if list>list[1]:
     city = driver.find_element_by_name("anyOfTheseWords")
     city.send_keys(list[1])

    #都市c列3つ以上がある場合
    #都市c列を次のキーワードを含まないへ入力
    #カリフォルニア入力
    if list>list[2]:
     city = driver.find_element_by_name("noneOfTheseWords")
     city.send_keys(list[2])

    #検索
    time.sleep(2)
    city.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
#ここまでを繰り返し --------------------------------------------------------------------
```

補足情報（Python/ツールのバージョンなど）
Python3.9.5/Windows10を利用しています。

もしわかる方いれば、教えていただけるとありがたいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 重複候補: [ExcelからTwitter（selenium）で特定の条件がある場合、繰り返し処理を行う方法について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/80783)

Comment: これ、利用規約的にいいやつでしたっけ？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。利用規約見てみましたが、特に問題ありませんでした。https://twitter.com/ja/tos

Answer (score 0):

リストの要素を取得して実現したい内容できました。
listの要素数を調べてサイズが0以上であれば、Twitterへ入力していきます。

参考URL：[[Python] listが空かどうか判定する方法2つ](https://qiita.com/yonedaco/items/d0f65ca3dad2e085a51d)

```
if len(list)>0:
 print("リスト0要素より大き場合")
 #都市b列を次のキーワード全体を含むへ入力
 city = driver.find_element_by_name("thisExactPhrase")
 city.send_keys(list[0])

if len(list)>1:
 print("リスト１要素より大き場合")
 #都市b列複数がある場合
 #都市b列を次のキーワードのいずれかを含むへ入力
 city = driver.find_element_by_name("anyOfTheseWords")
 city.send_keys(list[1])
```