# Excelからセルをコピーしてwebサイトの指定の項目に自動で貼り付けることはpythonで可能でしょうか。

Tags: python, python3

pythonを使用しExcelファイルのセルを一つ一つコピーして、特定のwebサイトの項目に自動で貼り付けることは可能でしょうか。
また、どのようにすればいいかも共有いただけたら幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2):

**pythonを使用しExcelファイルのセルを一つ一つコピーして、特定のwebサイトの項目に自動で貼り付けることは可能でしょうか。**

→ **可能です**
例えばこんな質問がそのような処理を行った関連のものです。
[ExcelからTwitter（selenium）で特定の条件がある場合、繰り返し処理を行う方法について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/80783/26370)

---

**どのようにすればいいかも共有いただけたら幸いです。**

→ それは漠然とし過ぎていて、範囲がとても広いので、簡単に答えられるものでは無く、このサイトの対象トピックからは外れます。

「特定のwebサイト」というからには、想定するWebサイトがあるでしょうからそれを明示して、また使用するExcelファイルも提示して、どのような処理を行いたいか自分である程度プログラムを作成してから上手くいかないところを質問してください。

これらのヘルプ記事を参考に。
[ここではどのようなトピックについて質問できますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
[どのような質問は避けるべきですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
[再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

そうしたことの前提知識も無いのでしたら、Pythonを使ったWebサイト操作の自動化の書籍やWeb記事を調べて勉強してください。